# How to automatically create a cart for a customer in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I would like to create automatically a cart for a customer with a product. Then the customer can login on the site and validate the cart.

I saw how to create a cart in my module but i don't understand how to affect the cart to a customer?

Comment: i am working with the backoffice controller : AdminOrders, i hope to transform it to do what i expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding created cart to customer is very simple:

```
$cart = new Cart();
//Add products or what so ever
$cart->id_customer = $my_customer_id;
$cart->update();
```

or simply update your `ps_cart` database table and set proper `id_customer` value. You can create a module with this code in a function with hook transplanted to actionAuthentication, which is executed after customer successful login to your e-shop.